# I can't seems to edit a field in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have this edit form on my index.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="client in vm.clients  | orderBy: '-ClientID'" ng-dblclick="vm.clickEditAction(client)">
        <td><img src="/img/trash.png" style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="vm.removeAction(client)" alt="Remove {{ client.ClientID }}" /></td>
        <td>{{ client.ClientID }}</td>                    
        <td>
             <span data-ng-hide="editMode">{{ client.ClientName }}</span>
             <input type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="client.ClientName" data-ng-required />
        </td>
        <td>{{ client.Country }}</td>
        <td>{{ client.Email }}</td>
        <td><button type="submit" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true; editAppKey(entry)" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
            <button type="submit" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, every time I edit the field and submit it, it doesn't update the field in the table database.

Here's my controller save:

```
vm.saveAction = function () {

    clientService.save(vm.clients, function (data) {

            if (data.success) {
                toastr.success('changes were saved.', 'Success');
                vm.clients = data.records;
            } else {
                toastr.error('Error saving :\n\n' + data.errorMessage, 'Error', {
                    timeOut: 0
                });
            }

        }, function (error) {
            toastr.error('Error saving :\n\n' + error, 'Error', {
                timeOut: 0
            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: I don't see saveAction being called in your HTML snippet. How are you calling it?

Comment: I have a button in my html that i wasn't able to include it:

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.saveAction()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save Changes</button>

Comment: What vm.saveAction() does is..it save a list (bulk insert)

Comment: Your client service code seems relevant too. Can you make a plunkr for this example?

Comment: when i tried to save it..it doesn't saved the edited field in the edit form..it's saved the old value

Comment: you need to show us your clientService code as well as the server side code that does the saving to the DB. Are you referring to the actual save to the DB or visually updating the text field?

Comment: actual save to the DB